# Neo4j: How can I return query results based on the number of connected nodes?

Tags: neo4j

I have the following schema:

```
(:Thread)
(:User)
(User)->[:PART_OF_THREAD]
```

Currently all threads will have an extra `(:User)` node connected to it which represents a bot (which does automated messages & etc.). Below is an example of the data for each thread (2 users + a BotUser)

```
(Thread)<-[:PART_OF]-(User1)
(Thread)<-[:PART_OF]-(User2)
(Thread)<-[:PART_OF]-(BotUser)
```

**NOTE:** Each user will have a thread with `BotUser` alone. E.g

```
(Thread)<-[:PART_OF]-(User2)
(Thread)<-[:PART_OF]-(BotUser)
```

I'm having troubles trying to query for the `User2` and `BotUser` thread. Since `BotUser` exists in every thread, if I query the thread between User2 and BotUser then neo4j will return all the threads that have User2 and BotUser in it, this is not what I want, I want to return JUST the thread with `BotUser` and `User2`. Here is the query I'm currently using:

```
MATCH (user1:USER {id: User1Id}) -[:PART_OF_THREAD]->(thread:THREAD)<-[:PART_OF_THREAD]-(:USER {id: BotUserId})
RETURN thread
```

How can I return the Thread with just `BotUser` and `User1`?

- Will I need to count the total number of users in the thread and ONLY return the thread WHERE users.length > 2?
- Is there anything else I could do?

*If something is not clear, feel free to ask some questions*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is about right, the fastest way to count the number of users being part of a thread is to get the degree of the `PART_OF` relationship on the thread :

```
MATCH (user1:USER {id: User1Id}) -[:PART_OF_THREAD]->(thread:THREAD)<-[:PART_OF_THREAD]-(:USER {id: BotUserId})
WHERE size((thread)<-[:PART_OF_THREAD]-()) = 2
RETURN thread
```